# Extract variable from a simple mathematical equation (Java, String)

Tags: java, regex, string

I will be handling a bunch of strings that will be of the following format:

```
"2*salary"
"salary+2"
"2*salary/3"
```

My goal is to pull out just "salary". I do not however want to eliminate non-characters because I might have something like "2*id3", a mixture of characters and numbers as the variable name (note: it will never be all numbers). I currently use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w_]+");
```

However, for something like "2*salary" this results in "2" and "salary" being found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

`Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]\\w+");`

... in other words, match the sequence of characters that *begins* with a letter. That'll match 'salary', but won't match '2' (and '2salary' too).

If you in fact do need to match `2salary`, use this:

`Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[A-Za-z]\\w+");`

(I have replaced `[\w_]` with just `\w`, it actually includes underscore).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this. It will definitely help a bit. I doubt I will run into many variables of the form "5id", but it is technically something I would like to look out for.

Comment: Well, I've updated the answer, but I thought not starting identifiers with numbers is kind of general convention. )

Answer (score 0):

That is because 2*salary matches twice your "word" character definition \w which is [a-zA-Z0-9_], the first is 2 and the and match is salary

In your case you need something like "[a-zA-Z][\w]*"